# C# Windows menu item help user manage open windows

Tags: c#, forms, menu

I want to have a window's menu item maintain a list of open windows that have been spawned by the main form. When a form is closed the list will be reduced. This feature exists in excel 2003 where clicking the window's menu item a list of open workbooks is given. I can write a singleton form where all other forms will report a form creation but I'm wondering whether this feature already exist in .Net. I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Application.OpenForms is what you need:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need a separate thread for each, and on each thread you call `Application.Run(yourform)`.
You can obviously create arrays of threads, forms et cettera.

Answer (score 0):

It's done for you Automatically.  Here's the link to show you how: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171654.aspx